# directory naming explanation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

Where can I find an explanation of directory names used in Ubuntu (the whole tree)?

- Why `etc`?
- When do I put my files in `/usr/local` when in `/home/usr` when in `/usr/local/bin` and when in `/var/lib/` or `/bin`?

Is there any rule, that tells when I have program *x*, it for sure must be placed here, and it's config files are here and data there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The questions you're asking are answered in the `hier(7)` man page. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man7/hier.7.html for an online version.

Answer (score 1):

look at [File System Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/)

also [LSB spec](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/execenvfhs.html) can be helpful.